# How can I get the height of a QListWidgetItem in a QListWidget in PyQt?

Tags: size, pyqt, qlistwidget

Actually, how can I extract size of gui elements in general in PyQt?

So far I have only found `sizeHint` mentioning anything regarding sizes in PyQt.

Could anyone please explain how sizes works in PyQt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, it's not possible to guarantee the *exact* sizes of widgets, because there are so many different factors that come in to play. Widgets will rendered differently depending on the window manager in use, the current GUI style, the fonts, etc - and each platform has it's own peculiarities.

To get a better understanding of all this, I would suggest you take a look at Qt's own overviews of [window geometry](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/application-windows.html#window-geometry), [widgets and layouts](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/widgets-and-layouts.html) and [layout management](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/layout.html).

To answer the specific question on the height of QListWidgetItems: they will have whatever height is calculated by the QListWidget when it lays out its items. This may take into account the items' `sizeHint`, which can be set programmatically with [QListWidgetItem.setSizeHint](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qlistwidgetitem.html#setSizeHint).

Comment: I agree, the concept of size in a GUI framework is not a trivial one. But in my example however it is a very simple one. I want to size a popup window (a `QListWidget` with the `Qt.Popup` flag set) to the exact size of its rows.

Comment: @c00kiemonster. You mean like a `QCompleter`? It would help if you added some code to your question that demonstrates the issues you're having. I can see how adjusting the _width_ is non-trivial, but setting the _height_ seems fairly straightforward.

Comment: Yes *setting* the height is trivial, but *getting* the item height was trickier. After a long while browsing the docs I found a way. It's not pretty, but I get the result I want: `w.rectForIndex(w.indexFromItem(w.item(0))).height()` with `w` being the `QListWidget`.

Comment: @c00kiemonster. Sorry, I meant setting the total height of the list widget. Glad you found a solution. Not exactly sure what you're trying to do, but I think you may have missed something simpler: [QAbstractItemView.sizeHintForRow](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qabstractitemview.html#sizeHintForRow). Apologies for not pointing this out earlier, but I assumed from your original question that you were already aware of it.